# Can Postgres specify which field triggered an error?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I run a query like this (just a made-up example):

```
update foo_table set field1=10000000000000, field2=100000000000000 where id=1;
```

And I get

```
ERROR:  integer out of range
```

How can I know whether the "out of range" field is `field1` or `field2`? Is there a setting to get a more specific error message?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any setting for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL often *can* tell you which field triggered an error. But in this case, no field triggered the error, so it can't. At the stage the error occurred the literals were being parsed, and PostgreSQL didn't yet know that they were being assigned to fields.

However, you should really be getting a better error than that. Consider, e.g.

```
test=>     SELECT INTEGER '10000000000000', INTEGER '100000000000000';
ERROR:  value "10000000000000" is out of range for type integer
LINE 1: SELECT INTEGER '10000000000000', INTEGER '100000000000000';
```

but yet

```
test=> update foo set field1=10000000000000, field2=100000000000000 where id=1;
ERROR:  integer out of range
```

(PostgreSQL 9.5).

It probably can't show the field here, but it should show the problem value and an error cursor like the first example. I'll see if I can find out why and submit a patch if I have time.

In the mean time you can work around it by quoting integer values so they're parsed as unknown-typed literals then converted:

```
test=> update foo set field1='10000000000000', field2='100000000000000' where id=1;
ERROR:  value "10000000000000" is out of range for type integer
LINE 1: update foo set field1='10000000000000', field2='100000000000...
                              ^
```

(Yes, this is SQL-standard)

---

The failure site is definitely different for the two invocations:

```
test=> \set VERBOSITY verbose

test=> update foo set field1=10000000000000, field2=100000000000000 where id=1;
ERROR:  22003: integer out of range
LOCATION:  int84, int8.c:1298

test=> update foo set field1='10000000000000', field2='100000000000000' where id=1;
ERROR:  22003: value "10000000000000" is out of range for type integer
LINE 1: update foo set field1='10000000000000', field2='100000000000...
                              ^
LOCATION:  pg_atoi, numutils.c:75
```